# Optimizar função para incluir classes procurando também nas sub-directorias

Tags: php, arquivo, classes, diretório, php-autoload

Tenho a seguinte função para incluir classes quando estamos a tentar utilizar uma classe que ainda não foi definida:

```php
/**
 * Attempt to load undefined class
 * @param object $class_name object class name
 */
function __autoload($class_name) {

    $incAutoload = dirname(__FILE__);
    $filename = $class_name.'.class.php';

    /* App Classes
     */
    $appPath = $incAutoload.'/classes/'.$filename;

    if (is_file($appPath)) {
        require_once($appPath);
        return true;
    }

    /* Website Classes
     */
    $sitePath = $incAutoload.'/classes/site/'.$filename;

    if (is_file($sitePath)) {
        require_once($sitePath);
        return true;
    }

    // ...
}
```

## Problema

Sempre que é criada uma sub-directoria para organizar as classes do projeto, tenho que editar este ficheiro e incluir uma verificação para essa sub-directoria:

```php
/* Google Classes
 */
$path = $incAutoload.'/classes/google/'.$filename;

if (is_file($path)) {
    require_once($path);
    return true;
}
```

## Pergunta

Como posso optimizar esta função de forma a que a mesma procure pela classe na directoria base `classes` mas também em qualquer uma das sub-directorias existentes?

Comment: Por que não utiliza o autoload do composer? Bem simples e prático, sem contar que seu código estará dentro de um padrão (PSR).

Comment: @Brayan Olá, é uma ideia. Se puderes, elabora uma resposta com essa solução e um exemplo de como funciona!

Comment: @Zuul, estive acompanhando as atualizações desta pergunta. Há bastante opções. Caso nenhuma das respostas tenha lhe agradado, não seria bom nos dar um *feedback* sobre isso para podermos melhorá-las?

Comment: @utluiz Na verdade, só hoje estou a testar cada uma das opções apresentadas para ver qual se "comporta" melhor, irei votar e atribuir a gratificação no prazo máximo de 3 dias ;) Até lá, ou pelo menos sem concluir os testes, não me posso manifestar por não estarem reunidas as condições para o efeito!

Answer (score 4):

Faça assim:

Arquivo na raiz:

```php
new \Root\Classe();
new \Root\foo\Tree();

spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
    $className = str_replace('Root\\', '', $className);
    $className = strtr($className, '\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    require $className.'.php';
});
```

Arquivo "Classe.php", também na raiz:

```php
namespace Root;

class Classe {
    public function __construct() {
        echo 'Raiz';
    }
}
```

Arquivo "Tree.php", localizado em "raiz/foo":

```php
namespace Root\foo;

class Tree {
    public function __construct() {
        echo 'Tree';
    }
}
```

Saída ao executar o primeiro código:

> Raiz Tree

Assim, você utiliza o namespace para fazer o autoload, combinando o namespace com o caminho físico, conforme eu tinha comentado. É rápido, simples, elegante e sem iteração, e você só carrega os arquivos que realmente interessam. Acessar o disco é um processo lento, se você tiver inúmeras classes, por um processo de iteração sobre pastas e arquivos, prejudicaria muito seu desempenho.

Comment: Sem dúvida se Namespaces puderem ser utilizados (sistemas não-legados) é a melhor alternativa.

Comment: Quem deu o voto negativo, é convidado a explicar o porquê nos comentários.

Comment: Fiz uma atualização no script de autoload, de acordo com as atuais especificações recomendadas de PHP.

Comment: O autoload PSR-4 do Composer funciona exatamente da mesma forma. [Documentação](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a **spl_autoload**, veja um exemplo:

```php
spl_autoload_register(NULL, FALSE);
spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
spl_autoload_register();

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../');
```

**OU**

```php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . __DIR__ . '/');
```

Comment: Além da solução usando Namespaces, esta é a melhor alternativa na minha opinião, mas se não me falha a memória existe uma limitação ao se usar `set_include_path`. No caso do Windows você pode definir um path+file name de no máximo 260 caracteres, além disso eu não tenho certeza mas acho que a própria definição de paths concatenados também tem limite. Desta forma quase sempre terá problemas ao utilizar-se desta solução.

Comment: "Por padrão, ela verifica todos os caminhos de inclusão por arquivos formados pelo nome da classe em minúsculo acrescido das extensões de arquivo .inc e .php" - Isso não significaria que o PHP, internamente, itera sobre os diretórios procurando os arquivos?

Answer (score 0):

Existem várias maneiras de solucionar isso. Algumas são iterativas, mas isso tem um preço em termos de performance. Eu faria algo semelhante ao que [propõe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2070/optimizar-funcao-para-incluir-classes-procurando-tambem-nas-sub-directorias/2155#2155) o Calebe Oliveira, porém sem utilizar a função `__autoload`, porque, segundo o [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.autoload.php):

> **Dica**
>   `spl_autoload_register()` fornece uma alternativa mais flexível para 'autoloading' de classes. Por esta razão, o uso da função `__autoload()` é desencorajado e pode estar [ficar] obsoleto ou ser removido no futuro.

Segundo [um comentário](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.spl-autoload-register.php#92514) presente no manual, do PHP 5.3 em diante basta criar uma estrutura de diretórios que corresponda à estrutura dos seus `namespaces`, e incluir o seguinte no início do seu código, uma única vez:

```php
spl_autoload_extensions(".php"); // comma-separated list
spl_autoload_register();
```

Answer (score -2):

## Cache em um Mapa

Uma das formas de fazer isso é armazenar um cachê de classes pelo nome num `array`. Fiz uma implementação básica:

```php
function list_classes($dir, $array = array()){
    $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach($files as $f){
        if($f != '.' && $f != '..'){
            if (strcmp(pathinfo($f)['extension'], 'php') == 0) {
                $array[basename($f, '.php')] = $f;
            } else if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$f)) {
                list_classes($dir.'/'.$f, $array);
            }
      }
    }
    return $array;
}


$classes_cache = list_classes(dirname(__FILE__));
var_dump($classes_cache);
```

O código acima lista recursivamente os arquivos `.php` do diretório atual, incluindo subdiretórios e armazena num `array` (ou mapa) cujo índice (ou chave) é o nome do arquivo sem a extensão.

Exemplo, dada uma chamada `list_classes('classes')` a partir de `main.php`:

```php
/
  main.php
  /classes
      Class1.php
      Class2.php
      /other_classes
          Class3.php
```

O resultado do array seria:

```php
{
  'Class1' => 'Class1.php',
  'Class2' => 'Class2.php',
  'Class3' => 'other_classes/Class3.php'
}
```

Enfim, criando este cache global, basta usá-lo no seu método de *autoload*.

Entretanto, haverá problema se houver arquivos com o mesmo nome em diretórios diferentes. Neste caso, seria interessante adicionar uma verificação se o item já existe no `array` e lançar um erro ou aviso.

Além disso, se houverem muitas pastas e diretórios, isso pode afetar um pouco o desempenho do script, mas será feito apenas uma vez. Então, se vale ou não a pena essa técnica, depende de quantas vezes o método de *autoload* será chamado.

## Lista de diretórios

Uma segunda abordagem é criar um `array` de diretórios e pesquisar se a classe existe em cada um deles. Note que a ordem do `array` ditará a prioridade da busca.

Segue um exemplo (baseado no [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713072/how-can-i-load-classes-from-multiple-directories-with-autoload)):

```php
function __autoload($class_name) {

    $array_paths = array(
        'classes/', 
        'classes/site'
    );

    foreach($array_paths as $path) {
        $file = sprintf('%s%s/class_%s.php', dirname(__FILE__), $path, $class_name);
        if(is_file($file)) {
            include_once $file;
        } 

    }
}
```

O array de diretórios poderia ser carregado automaticamente com um algoritmo similar ao anterior:

```php
$array_paths = glob(dirname(__FILE__).'/../*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

Dessa forma, não é necessário percorrer todos os subdiretórios, mas a cada carregamento de classe será necessário olhar o sistema de arquivos.

## Padrão de Nomenclatura

Outra técnica usada por alguns frameworks, como o `Zend Framework` é colocar um *underline* no nome das classes para representar o caminho a partir de um diretório base. Por exemplo, a classe `Animal_Cachorro` fricaria dentro no diretório `/Animal`.

Segue um código de exemplo (baseado no [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280347/autoload-classes-from-different-folders)):

```php
function __autoload($class_name) {
    $filename = str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, strtolower($class_name)).'.php';
    $file = dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$filename;
    if (!file_exists($file)) return FALSE;
    include $file;
}
```

Este é o método mais direto e com melhor desempenho, pois é feito apenas uma cesso ao sistema de arquivos.

Porém, do meu ponto de vista, ele "suja" o nome das classes. Não me parece boa prática misturar a estrutura de diretórios com os nomes das suas classes apenas para facilitar a construção de frameworks e método utilitários.

Comment: As duas primeiras técnicas são horríveis, ja a última seria a melhor no ponto de vista de desempenho. E quanto a sujar o nome das classes, nas versões mais recentes do PHP existe namespaces, o que pode substituir os "_", então isso não é justificativa.

Comment: @WoLfulus Eu citei 3 abordagens possíveis sem usar namespaces. Fiz considerações sobre o desempenho, talvez você não tenha lido com atenção. Já existe outra resposta que fala da questão do namespace, não vou repeti-la. Além disso, essas técnicas "horríveis" são a única opção se você não quer ou não pode usar namespaces ou não pode refatorar todas as suas classes. Só porque existe um jeito "melhor" de fazer as coisas, não significa que técnicas alternativas e mais antigas são sejam importantes para atender a requisitos e contextos específicos.

Answer (score -3):

A SPL tem classe [DirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) para listar diretorios  e arquivos. A ideia é pegar dos os diretorios abaixo de classes e retornar como um array e depois listar todos os arquivos de cada pasta.

```php
function listarDiretorios($dirInicial){
        $dir = new  DirectoryIterator($dirInicial);

        $dirs = array();
        foreach ($dir as $item){
            if(!$item->isDot() && $item->isDir()){
                $dirs[] = $item->getFileName();
            }
        }
        return $dirs;
}

function listarArquivos($raiz, $dirs){
    $files = array();
    foreach ($dirs as $item){
        $dir = new  DirectoryIterator($raiz.$item);
        foreach ($dir as $subitem){
            if(!$subitem->isDot() && $subitem->isFile()){
                $files[$item][] = $subitem->getFileName();
            }
        }
                
    }
    return $files;
}
```

uso:

```php
//essas constantes podem ser definados em um arquivo config.
define('PATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
define('CLASSES_PATH', dirname(__FILE__). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'classes'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    
$dir = listarDiretorios(CLASSES_PATH);
$files = listarArquivos(CLASSES_PATH, $dir);
```